# how to use mask using numba @jit

Tags: python, numpy, numba, jit

I would like to do simple division and average using jit function where nopython = True.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit,prange,typed

A = np.array([[2,2,2],[1,0,0],[1,2,1]], dtype=np.float32)
B = np.array([[2,0,2],[0,1,0],[1,2,1]],dtype=np.float32)
C = np.array([[2,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,2]],dtype=np.float32)
```

my jit function goes

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def test(a,b,c):
    mask = a+b >0
    div = np.divide(c, a+b, where=mask)
    result = div.mean(axis=1)

    return result

test_res = test(A,B,C)
```

however this throws me an error, what would be the workaround for this? I am trying to do this without the loop, any lights would be appreiciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numba doesn't support some arguments for some of numpy modules (e.g. [`np.mean()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64314661/13394817) or [`where` in `np.divid`](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7373#issue-988570347)) (including ["axis" argument](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1269) which is not included). You can do this by some alternative codes like:

```
@nb.njit("float64[::1](float32[:, ::1], float32[:, ::1], float32[:, ::1])")  # parallel --> , parallel=True
def test(a, b, c):
    result = np.zeros(c.shape[0])
    c = np.copy(c)
    for i in range(c.shape[0]):     # parallel --> for i in nb.prange(c.shape[0]):
        for j in range(c.shape[1]):
            if a[i, j] + b[i, j] > 0:
                c[i, j] = c[i, j] / (a[i, j] + b[i, j])
            result[i] += c[i, j]

    return result / c.shape[1]
```

JAX library can be used to accelerate as:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

@jax.jit
def test_jax(a, b, c):
    mask = a + b > 0
    div = jnp.where(mask, jnp.divide(c, a + b), c)
    return jnp.mean(div, axis=1)
```

Comment: How could we make this better? Better in a sense that we can use one for loop instead of two? Very interesting

Comment: @dakjdlajsl I was written this code very fast and put it here as answer that contains two loops. I removed one of them. I added some commented codes for parallelization, too. The better optimized code may could be written with performance experts (which is not the aim of this question), and need to be asked in another post if you think it is needed. But, IMO, this code is written in an acceptable good scheme now.

Comment: @dakjdlajsl Do you need another solution?? In your question you have said that you have tried "without the loop". Do you want use numba without it??
[Numba is entirely happy with looping code](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7373#issuecomment-915924996). If so, you need using other libraries like JAX.

Comment: @dakjdlajsl I have added JAX one to the answer just for getting familiar (not explaining), you can see some benchmarks on [this temporary colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zzEm6gMc-3u6aDil2YsFLcD0_ZwqCyTt?usp=sharing). As it is shown, JAX will have better performances on larger arrays. **Note that** I have modified the code and added `c = np.copy(c)`. without this change `C` array will be changed. Now `C` will not be modified in function calls.